# In Flask, how to make retrieving data query from PostgreSQL DB - using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to make a query which is responsible for retrieving data from PostgreSQL database.

I have built a PostgreSQL query and it works well on the Pgadmin. But I'm not sure how to convert this query using SQLAlchemy.

```
SELECT SUM(click) as click,
    SUM(nSignup) as nsignup,
    SUM(nDepo) as ndepo,
    SUM(valDepo) as valdepo,
    SUM(numDepo) as numdepo,
    SUM(spotsTurn) as spotsturn,
    SUM(commission) as commission,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM myDate)::text || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateto)::text || EXTRACT(WEEK FROM myDate)::text AS datefield 
FROM bet365s 
GROUP BY datefield
ORDER By datefield;
```

I think the query above should be converted like as follows if I use SQLAlchemy.

But I'm not sure how to convert this query using SQLAlchemy.

```
db.session.query(Bet365, func.sum(Bet365.click), func.sum(Bet365.nsignup), func.sum(Bet365.ndepo), \
func.sum(Bet365.valdepo), func.sum(Bet365.numdepo),func.sum(Bet365.spotsturn), func.sum(Bet365.commission), \
func.year(Bet365.myDate )....)
```

I would like to know how can I do this.